# Notification in TabActivity in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-tabhost, tabactivity

I have TabActivity which has 4 tabs. I wnat to give notification on tab. One is Missed call tab on which I want to show unread count as shown in screenshots of

https://market.android.com/details?id=se.alexanderblom.gmailunreadcount&feature=search_result

Unread count in this image is on application icon but i want it on tab as similar to badge in iphone i want in android.

Can you give reference of any tutorial or tell in how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the version of `setIndicator()` on your `TabSpec` that takes a custom `View` that you create (e.g., inflate from a layout file). Then, you can get that `View` later on by calling `getChildTabViewAt()` on your `TabWidget`. You can then update your indicator as you see fit.